# jscript error in page

Tags: php, html, file-io, jscript

Hello I somewhere missing error since it throws function is not defined, but in other test file same function works fine.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['action']) && isset($_GET['friend']))
{
    include_once "dbconnect.php";
    $act = $_GET['action'];
    $idas = $_GET['id'];
    $un = $_GET['friend'];
    $act = $DBcon->real_escape_string($act);
    $un = $DBcon->real_escape_string($un);
    $idas = $DBcon->real_escape_string($idas);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE `pass`='$un'";
    if ($query = $DBcon->query($sql))
    {
        $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if ($row_cnt != 0)
        {
            if($act == 0)
            {
                $sql2 = "DELETE FROM `gyventojai` WHERE `ID`='$idas'";
                if ($query2 = $DBcon->query($sql2))
                {
                    echo "User deleted!";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<script>window.parent.location = 'index.php';</script>";
                }
            }
            else if($act == 1)
            {
                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `ID`='$idas'";
                if ($query2 = $DBcon->query($sql2))
                {
                    $uDB = $query2->fetch_array();
                    ?>
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            <div id="edituser">
                                <form>
                                    ID: <?php echo $uDB[0]; ?><br>
                                    Nick:<input type="text" id="nick" value="<?php echo $uDB[1]; ?>" required>
                                    <br>
                                    Log id ID:<input type="text" id="logid" value="<?php echo $uDB[2]; ?>" required>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="friend" value="<?php echo $un; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="oldname" value="<?php echo $uDB[1]; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $uDB[0]; ?>">
                                    <button type="button" onclick="saveuser()" id="save_btn">Save</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div id="respond"></div>
                        </body>
                    </html>
                    <?php
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<script>window.parent.location = 'index.php';</script>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<script>window.parent.location = 'index.php';</script>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>window.parent.location = 'index.php';</script>";
        }
        $query->close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>window.parent.location = 'index.php';</script>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<script>window.parent.location = 'index.php';</script>";
}
?>
```

Thanks for help! Code is not working where id=edituser, where createuser function it throws error that createuser is not defined.

Comment: but `createuser` is not defined... Where do you expect it to come from? I assume `scripts/scripts.js`? Have you checked your browser error log? Does this resource load successfully? [edit] your question to include the contents of this script.

Comment: yes it come from scripts.js file and it loads fine function is: function saveuser()
{
    alert("fff");
}

Comment: `saveuser` != `createuser`

Comment: wrong function i mean saveuser, miss typed, my bad.

Comment: post the code, and post a screenshot showing that the js file has been loaded successfully by the browser. also, post the full error message from the js console.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: saveuser is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick, photo link: http://www.part.lt/img/a67eea6517b2bfd4a7544b06e97655e5936.png

Comment: Any ideas about this problem?

Comment: Anyways what could cause to not see that function?